# Get IntPtr value from BitmapImage or stream in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, image-processing, uwp

I'm working with image processing in WinForm and it work very well when I have Bitmap and BitmapData, I can easily get IntPtr from it. But in UWP, I have no way to get IntPtr from them. So do we have any way to do that?

**UPDATE:** If we cannot get IntPtr value, can we get the pointer address for that image? Something like this in WinForm:

byte* src = (byte*) BitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer( );

Comment: An `IntPtr` to what? The `BitmapImage` instance? The pixel data? Something else?

Comment: I wanna get an IntPtr to get the pointer address from that. (the pixel address that image locate in the memory). So from that I can work with it pixel by pixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get pxiel data from file stream via BitmapDecoder and PixelDataProvider:

```
Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png")).OpenReadAsync();
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        byte[] buffer = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
```

Then you could get Intptr from byte array via unsafe code

```
unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p = buffer)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
                // do you stuff here
            }
        }
```

If compile unsafe code, you need to enable the **Allow Unsafe Code** option in project's build property.